# MYSQL Including a character into the query

Tags: mysql

So far, I have the following SQL Statement:

```
SELECT users.ID, user_email, SUM(points) as totalPoints
FROM wp_users AS users
INNER JOIN wp_wc_points_rewards_user_points AS rewards ON users.id = rewards.user_id
WHERE points <> 0
GROUP BY user_email
HAVING SUM(points) > 0  
ORDER BY `totalPoints` DESC
```

What I am getting stuck with and have discovered is that I have to include `wp_wc_points_rewards_user_points_log` as `log` connecting by `users.id`

In the `log` table also has a column called `points` with negative values `-#` (Wanting to select only values with "-") and I need to take `log.points` - `totalPoints` and then give the true "Total Points"

Comment: please described how the three tables are related (one to one, one to many etc). And what is the purpose of log table?

Comment: wp_users is one to many but the points tables only have the user_id and not the e-mail (This comes from wp_users) I am pulling apart Wordpress tables here

Comment: Sorry, this isn't helpful. How about you post some sample data from both reward points table for a specific user, and the expected total.

Comment: Better create a DB fiddle here - https://www.db-fiddle.com/, and share the link to run and analyze